# Image Slider CSS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to make an image slider by making changes in the `src` of the `img` tag.

```
<div style="overflow : hidden; ">
    <img class="img-responsive" id="page-body-bg" src="images/ccbg1.jpg" style=" left : 0; display : absolute;">
</div>
```

The CSS snippet is

```
#page-body-bg
{
    width : 100%;
}
```

What i have tried is

```
setInterval(function() { 
  $("#page-body-bg").fadeOut(200, function() {
    $("#page-body-bg").attr("src","images/ccbg2.jpg");
  }).fadeIn(200);
}, 3000);
```

This is not slider but it fades out and then fades in again.
(Apart from question : How can i remove the delay between fade in and fade out in above example.)

I am having difficulty in making slider by similar method.

Comment: In your code `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` speed is set as 200 milliseconds. Setting the value to 0 removes the delay. Ex. `.fadeIn(0)`

Comment: @Pugazh : it removes the delay but removes the animation.

Comment: @Punit Pal : You cannot remove the delay and keep the speed on the same element (#page-body-bg). A quick start : create a wrapper for your images, and use as many img tag as images you have, and play with index() to display images one after another

Comment: @EdenSource : Can you please elaaborate?

Comment: I made a mistake, it is eq(), and not index(). Please find a quick answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using many `img` tags allow you to fade images in the same time. In the exemple, I level up the fade transition speed to show you the effect.

Here is the elaborated answer : [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jnozz1kz/)

This is a quick answer, there are many ways to do this more easily, but for our exemple, this is enought I guess.